# Manipular dicionários dentro de outros dicionários

Tags: python

```
Alunos = {
    111: {
        'nome' : 'Joao',  
        'curso' : 'ADS'
    },

    222: { 
        'nome' : 'Pedro',
        'curso' : 'SI'
    },

    333: { 
        'nome' : 'Maria',
        'curso' : 'SI'
    }
}
```

Preciso fazer um script para mostrar os nomes dos alunos cujo curso seja SI.
Não estou conseguindo ter lógica e o professor não ensinou isso, já procurei na internet e não consegui nada para dá uma luz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta filtrar os valores do dicionário com base no curso, obtendo o nome de cada aluno:

```
nomes = (aluno['nome'] for aluno in Alunos.values() if aluno['curso'] == 'SI')
```

E, para exibir os nomes:

```
for nome in nomes:
    print(nome)
```

Que exibiria:

```
Pedro
Maria
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/QuizzicalStupidParallelalgorithm) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/RWxzNo) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/34e37f937b3989c02ff94d9e3caeac90)</sup>

Comment: Obrigado Anderson